# Difference between \LoadClass and \LoadClassWithOptions

Tags: document-classes

Can anyone tell me the difference between those two commands?

Edit: Thanks for the answers, but I didn't get the clue yet. Here's an example:

test.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{mytestclass}
...
```

mytestclass.cls

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e} 
\ProvidesClass{testclass}[2011/01/30 v0.1 testclass]
\LoadClass{book}
```

or

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e} 
\ProvidesClass{testclass}[2011/01/30 v0.1 testclass]
\LoadClassWithOptions{book}
```

In both examples the options `a4paper` and `oneside` are passed to `book`. So, I don't see any difference in the result.

Comment: it is not the same! Try `\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,openany]{mytestclass}`
`openany` is not valid with `\LoadClass`. Insert two `\chapter` commands in the test doc

Comment: Yes, I understand it now. See below. I added it to your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`\LoadClass[options]{name}` load class *name* with the listed options
`\LoadClassWithOptions{name}` load class *name* with the same options of the current class. For example

```
\documentclass[foo,bar]{baz}
```

inside the `baz.cls` there can be a

```
\LoadClassWithOptions{book}% is loaded with options `foo` and `bar`
```

or

```
\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{name}
...
\LoadClass[default options]{name}
```

Comment: Oh, I see. So there's only  a difference when I use \LoadClassWithOptions inside a .tex file. When I use one of those commands insde a .cls file I get the same result. Right?

Comment: No, even if you use it inside a .cls, `\LoadClassWithOptions` will load the class using the options specified in the `\documentclass` of the main .tex file.

Comment: @Herbert: your code would cause an `Two \LoadClass commands` error.

Comment: The question is only if you want to pass the options to the loaded class or not. There is also a command `\PassOptionsToClass{..}{...}` and both are used inside the `baz.cls`

Comment: @Herbert, I thought so, but just wanted to point it out for Thorsten.

Comment: @Martin: then a correct name would make sense ;-)

Comment: @Herbert: Thanks, I've got it using the following lines: `\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}\ProcessOptions\LoadClass{book}`

Comment: @Thorsten, yes, that is ok

Answer (score 21):

The command

```
\LoadClassWithOptions{class}
```

will load the *class* using the options specified in the main document.

The command

```
\LoadClass[options]{class}
```

will load the *class* using the specified *options* and **does not include** the options of the main document.

In your example you probably don't see much difference because the options specified in the `\documentclass` are probably the defaults for `scrbook` anyway.

But consider this example of a file `baseclass.cls`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{baseclass}[2011/01/30 v0.1 baseclass]
\LoadClass{article}

\def\funny{Is not funny}
\DeclareOption{funny}{\def\funny{Is funny!}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
```

Then `myclass.cls`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2011/01/30 v0.1 myclass]
\LoadClass{baseclass}
```

And `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[funny]{myclass}

\begin{document}
\funny
\end{document}
```

Even if you specify the `funny` option, it won't be applied in `baseclass`. But it will be applied if you use the command `\LoadClassWithOptions` in `myclass.cls`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've got it now. Unfortunately I cannot accept more than one answer.

Answer (score 7):

From the [LATEX2ε for class and package writers](http://www.latex-project.org/guides/clsguide.pdf) guide:

> A LATEX class can load one other class as follows:

```
\LoadClass[<options>]{<class-name>}[<date>]
```

> The following commands can be used in the common case that you want to 
>   simply load a class or package file with exactly those options that are being 
>   used by the current class.

```
\LoadClassWithOptions{<class-name>}[<date>]
\RequirePackageWithOptions{<package>}[<date>]
```

---

You cannot use `\LoadClass` or `\LoadClassWithOptions` inside a main document **after** `\documentclass`, only in the `.cls` loaded with it. This would cause an error. However, you can, if you really want it, use this macros **before** the `\documentclass`. In this case no main class option are set yet, so `\LoadClassWithOptions` would not make sense at all.

Comment: how can you use `\LoadClass{article}` before a `\documentclass{book}`??

Comment: I couldn't tell you a usecase for it. I simple tested the different combinations and found out that it works without an error. It doesn't make much sense IMHO.

Comment: The `\LoadClass{article}` before a `\documentclass{book}` causes an error ...or with any other combination of existing classes which define for example the font size with `\newcommand`

Comment: @Herbert: You are right, this combination doesn't make sense and doesn't work most the time. I just mentioned it as theoretical possibility without thinking much about it if it makes sense.  I tested it with `minimal` loaded before `article` and it worked. Note that I tested the internal avoid-two-classes mechanism of `\LoadClass` and `\documentclass`, not if two classes really work which each other.

Answer (score 1):

Just went through the experience myself. To add to the existing answers a more concrete answer.

main.tex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,9pt]{myclass}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

If you always want to use the options `a4paper,11pt` and want to ignore the user options specified in `\documentclass` in main.tex, then myclass.cls:

```
\LoadClass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
```

If you want the user options specified in `\documentclass` in main.tex and no more than that, then myclass.cls:

```
\LoadClassWithOptions{article}
```

That's why `\LoadClassWithOptions` has no optional argument `[<options-list>]`

If you always want to use the option `a4paper`, and the user can specify other options in `\documentclass` in main.tex, then myclass.cls:

```
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[a4paper]{article}
```

Source: Sections 3.2-3.6 of https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/clsguide-historic.pdf