# How can I change the aspect ratio in beamer without passing the aspectratio option?

Tags: beamer, themes

I started to create a custom theme for beamer slides, and I want to change the default aspect ratio for this theme. Of course I can use `\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}` in every document, but I'd like to keep everything in *.sty files. In `beamer.cls` I found definitions of `\beamer@paperwidth` and `\beamer@paperheight`, but setting these lengths in `bemerthemeMYTHEME.sty`  as follows has no effect on the result.

```
\mode<presentation>
\setlength\beamer@paperwidth{16.00cm}
\setlength\beamer@paperheight{10.00cm}
```

What would be a proper way to change the default aspect ratio in *.sty? Shell I use `beamerouterthemeMYTHEME.sty` or `bemerthemeMYTHEME.sty` for this?

Comment: Themes really should not be changing the aspect ratio: the two are separate concepts. Can you explain a bit more what you are doing: it sounds like you are making a custom class based on `beamer` more than a theme.

Comment: @Papiro This is not a duplicate, IMO. Based on her/his post, zeliboba already knows how to set the aspect ratio. The question here is how to set the aspect ratio *after* `\documentclass{...}`.

Comment: I try to translate corporate PowerPoint style to beamer, they use 16:9 aspect ratio, and I do not want to keep it as an option to `\documentclass`. Could you please elaborate a bit more on the "concepts"? For me it is just changing the defaults, you can do it with margins, why not with paper size?

Comment: The problem is that a lot of the document settings derive from options passed to the class (such as `aspectratio=169`). You could probably adjust those settings after `\documentclass{...}` but you would probably have to rerun a lot of lines from the class file in order to get the desired result. I had a similar problem a while back: I wanted the output to look just as if I had loaded the `smaller` beamer class option while keeping all my tweaks in my .sty file. It turned out to be unwieldy and I ended up simply passing `smaller` as an option to the class: `\documentclass[smaller]{beamer}`.

Comment: So you can do two things: 1) simply pass the class option in the `\documentclass{...}` command; 2) as Joseph Wright suggested, modify the `beamer` class file to create your own, which would set the aspect ratio to a different value by default.

Comment: @Jubobs You don't need to modify `beamer`, just create a small wrapper class that loads `beamer` with the required options.

Comment: ***Not*** a duplicate as proposed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A wrapper class `beamer16x9.cls` can be easily written:

```
\ProvidesClass{beamer16x9}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{beamer}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\endinput
```

Then starting a document with

```
\documentclass[<options>]{beamer16x9}
```

is equivalent to saying

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,<options>]{beamer}
```

The `beamer16x9.cls` file should be in one of the canonical places where TeX engines look for input.

Comment: That's great; much easier than my approach (I'll delete it). However, the difference between typing `\documentclass[<options>]{beamer16x9}` and typing `\documentclass[aspectratio=169,<options>]{beamer}` is marginal. I would personally just resign myself to doing the latter.

Comment: @Jubobs With a custom class you might also make other changes, for example the theme-like stuff the OP asked about.

Comment: Perfect! I was looking for something like this, thanks.

Comment: Note: this topic may be useful to understand the details of class loading http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9908/difference-between-loadclass-and-loadclasswithoptions