# How to crop frame in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, paper-size

I am working on some presentation with beamer. However, I need a specific frame size (not the default values of aspect ratios). What I need is to crop the frame around its content and control the padding size. For example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) circle(3cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And here is what I got:

[image]

What I am looking for is to get:

[image]

Comment: You can't use `standalone`, as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/343005/586? Note that with the `tikz` class option, each `tikzpicture` will be a separate page.

Comment: see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112095/how-can-i-change-the-aspect-ratio-in-beamer-without-passing-the-aspectratio-opti

Comment: @TimothyTruckle No, that is a different problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beamer is not meant to automatically adjust paper sizes, but two possibilities:

1. Adjust the paper size manually

   ```
   \documentclass{beamer}

   \geometry{papersize={8cm,8cm}}

   \mode<presentation>{ }
   \beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

   \usepackage{tikz}

   \begin{document}
   \begin{frame}
   \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw (0,0) circle(3cm);
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{frame}
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]
2. Use another class which can automatically resize based on the content, e.g. `standalone`.

   ```
   \documentclass[tikz, margin=1cm]{standalone}

   \begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw (0,0) circle(3cm);
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: Sorry for taking liberties with your code. The `tikz` class option is nice, because then each `tikzpicture` gets its own page.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks! I did not know about this advantage!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. But I tried the second solution before and the problem is that I need to build one frame with beamer and build covers on it using \uncover, to fix the shape position and build on it. When I used the second solution I faced the problem of inconsistent tikzpictures sizes.

Comment: @AhmedHawary Then take the first solution :)

Comment: I think this could partially solve my problem, but if there is some automatic solution that would be great. Thanks for being helpful! :)