# How to set options in a .cls file

Tags: class-options

Suppose I'm writing a `foo` class which at some point calls

```
LoadClassWithOptions{book}
```

I would like to be able to pass either `oneside` or `twoside` to the book class based on various other considerations. Is there a way to explicitly set the option prior to calling `LoadClassWithOptions` or do I have to use `LoadClass` and pass the appropriate option explicitly?

Comment: Does [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9909/62152) explanation answer your question?

Comment: @VáclavPavlík: Unfortunately, I don't think so. I'm trying to decide what options to pass to book based on what options are passed to foo.

Comment: @DanielSank The linked answer includes `\PassOptionsToClass`, which seems to be what you want:  you set those up, then just do `\LoadClass`, and only those options you've requested get forwarded.