# Inserting code before Lyx generated preamble

Tags: hyperref, lyx, urls, preamble

I wish to use the `url` package with the `hyphens` option and the `hyperref` package. Because the `hyperref` package loads the `url` package, I have to pass the `hyphens` option to the `url` package before it is load. So I need to place the code

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
```

before the Lyx-generated component of the preamble. How do I do that?

Please note:

- I am aware that I could load the hyperref package in the preamble (and disable it in the interface). I'm trying to avoid this as this defeats the point of Lyx. I'm also looking to Lyx as a more user-friendly tool for my institute than directly tex-coding.
- I am aware of the `breaklinks` option for the `hyperref` package but that requires overriding automatic identification of drivers (to force it to use the `pdftex` driver).

EDIT: Feature request has been lodged with Lyx development team at:
https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/10567

Comment: My only suggestion is what you already said: disable hyperref in LyX and load it yourself. I know that's not ideal though. If you have an idea for how LyX could make this easier, please make an enhancement request at https://www.lyx.org/trac

Comment: I've followed through on your suggestion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to achieve the output you want, add the following to Document > Settings > Local Layout:

```
PackageOptions url hyphens
Requires url
```

Hit "Validate" and "Apply", and you're done.

Answer (score 5):

In general, the only way (currently) to gain access to the part between `\documentclass` and the first packages that are loaded is to write your own layout:

1. Find the one that most suits your needs. Let's say `Memoir`:

   [image]
2. Find the accompanying `.layout` inside your LyX layout folder:

   [image]

   Make a copy of this and call it (say) `myclass.layout`.
3. Edit `myclass.layout`, making sure the first three lines look like this:

   ```
   #% Do not delete the line below; configure depends on this
   #  \DeclareLaTeXClass[myclass]{MyCLaSS}
   #  \DeclareCategory{Books}
   ```

   The optional argument for `\DeclareLaTeXClass` - `myclass` here - will point to a class that you'll write called `myclass.cls`. The mandatory argument - `MyCLaSS` here - will point to the list entry under Document Class within LyX. The mandatory argument for `\DeclareCategory` points to the category under which `MyCLaSS` will appear within the Document Class list.
4. Create `myclass.cls`:

   ```
   \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e} 
   \Providesclass{myclass}[My custom class]
   \LoadClassWithOptions{memoir}
   ```

   See [Difference between `\LoadClass` and `\LoadClassWithOptions`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9908/5764). Also include whatever you want additionally here, like

   ```
   \PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
   ```

   Store this file somewhere within your TEXMF local tree:

   [image]

   See [Where do I place my own `.sty` or `.cls` files, to make them available to all my `.tex` files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/5764)
5. Run `texhash` to update your filename database.
6. In LyX, run Tools > Reconfigure.

   [image]
7. Restart LyX.
8. Create a new document and Document > Settings... > Document Class and choose your `MyCLaSS`:

   [image]

Comment: It's an impressive amount of effort you've gone to, but I feel the correct answer is actually '"you can't". Writing your own layout files to me is more contrary to the point of Lyx then writing your own preamble.

Comment: @Charlie: Well, LyX is extendable in this way. Until a feature request for something alternative is made available, I'm guessing this is a viable LyX-like solution.