# LyX: import package before LyX-added LaTeX commands

Tags: lyx, preamble, lyx-layouts

When adding something to the LyX preamble and converting to TeX, it adds the lines after LyX package imports (`\usepackage{amsmath}` and the like), after LyX specific LaTeX commands (`\pdfpageheight\paperheight`), and after Textclass specific LaTeX commands:

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{\protect\definitionname}
```

I would like to import a package at the same time the "normal" packages are imported (`amsmath`, etc.). I saw [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354284/inserting-code-before-lyx-generated-preamble) and the accepted answer seemed relevant, but I can't make it work. When I add:

```
PackageOptions mypackage foo
Requires mypackage
```

to the Local Layout, it adds the line `\PassOptionsToPackage{foo}{mypackage}` before the `\usepackage` lines, but nothing else.

Comment: I've asked your questions like yours before, so I understand if you cannot, but it would be helpful if you asked what you really want to do and give a minimal example of something where you get an error.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
AddToPreamble
\usepackage[this]{that}
EndPreamble
```

in the local layout, cf. Help --> Customization, section 5.3.4.

Comment: This almost works: it puts it before Textclass specific LaTeX commands, but before Textclass commands.

Comment: @Ted I'm guessing a bit here, but to get full control you probably need to make a new layout file. Start with a copy of the one corresponding to the documentclass you use, e.g. `article.layout` (on my system that is found in `/usr/share/lyx/layouts/`, place the modified copy in the [user directory](https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/UserDir))