# \end{nolinenumbers} not working for Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx

I'm using LyX.

The code `\end{nolinenumbers}` is not working for Table of Contents.

Who can help?

[image]

[image]

```
% Quellcode vorschauen

%% LyX 2.0.8.1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{extarticle}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=3cm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=true,pdfborder={0 0 0},backref=false,colorlinks=true]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.

\usepackage{etoolbox}\usepackage{lineno}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{etoolbox,lineno}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\setlength{\linenumbersep}{10pt}
\renewcommand{\linenumberfont}{\normalfont\tiny\sffamily\color{gray}}


% \patchcmd{}{}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@startsection}{\@ifstar}{\nolinenumbers\@ifstar}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@xsect}{\ignorespaces}{\linenumbers\ignorespaces}{}{}

\linenumbers

\usepackage{xcolor}\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage{tocstyle}\usepackage{enumitem}\usepackage{mathabx}\usepackage{color}\usepackage{soulutf8}\usepackage{microtype}

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi}.}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\labelenumi\arabic{enumii}.}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\labelenumii\arabic{enumiii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiv}{\alph{enumiv})}


\newtocstyle[KOMAlike][leaders]{chapterwithdot}{
  \settocfeature{pagenumberbox}{\makebox[1em][r]}% Platz für Seitenzahl
  \settocfeature[-1]{leaders}{\hfill}% keine Punkte bei part
  \settocfeature[-1]{pagenumberbox}{\phantom}% keine Seitenzahl bei part
  }
\usetocstyle{chapterwithdot}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.9}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\newpage{}\begin{nolinenumbers} \tableofcontents{}\end{nolinenumbers}

\clearpage\pagenumbering{arabic}

\setcounter{page}{6}\newpage{}


\section{weijfwoijfewfe}


\subsection{wefijwoijfeoiwfe}
\begin{quote}
\begin{singlespace}
\noindent joiwjeoiwjfoiwjfe\end{singlespace}

\end{quote}

\subsection{wfejwojfeowijfowf}

woiujfeoiwjfeoiwjfeoiwfe
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there someone who can help?

Comment: It work for me, so without more information we can only guess. Reduce your  document *as far as possible while still produce the problem*  and then paste in your question the complete LaTeX source (export to pdflatex or copy it  from View > Code Preview Pane > Complete source. It should be some like `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lineno}
\begin{document}
\linenumbers
\begin{nolinenumbers}
\tableofcontents{}
\end{nolinenumbers}
\section{aaaa}xxxxx\section{bbbb}zzzz
\end{document}`

Comment: Does that help? See first post.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I dont understand. There is non makeatletter in my preamble.

Comment: There are always a `\makeatletter` as in the code that yourself have posted whenever you add something to the preamble with Document > Settings > Latex Preamble, but that command is in the non visible part of the preamble. To be clear, the preamble that you can edit is only the part between  that `\makeatletter` and the  `\makeatother` (that also is invisible).

Comment: Sorry, I do not explained well in my first comment. The problem is that  `\usepackage{etoolbox}` is between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. Moving the package just before of just after that commands  solve the problem. Unfortunately, editing the preamble in LyX only allow put packages in that `\makeatletter  ...  \makeatother` zone but you have a solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354284/inserting-code-before-lyx-generated-preamble).

Comment: So what should I put in the "Local Layout"-field?

Comment: I'm afraid so, although I have not tried it. The 99% of the time is enough with the layouts available for standard document classes, but if you need more control over the preamble or use another kind of document, most probably you will need to entangle with the layouts . Avoid these layouts is a main reason for me to edit LaTeX directly instead of using LyX.